# AWS Transit Gateway Equivalent services in Azure

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, compare, firewall, gateway

Is there any AWS Transit Gateway Equivalent services in Azure?

Azure docs

Is this similar to Azure Firewall?

Comment: I don't think. Because AWS transit gateway was just launched in last November.

Answer (score 2):

Both are offering the same feature service to connect VPC/VNet of their cloud infrastructure and on-premise network site-to-site VPN. It will work as a central place to connect cloud networks and multiple on-premise networks located at different physical location/country using the cloud's own backbone infra.

Using this service customers can connect their various branch office/data center via Azure/AWS's backbone.

AWS Transit Gateway
[image: AWS's Transit gateway]

Azure Virtual WAN

[image: Azure's Virtual WAN]

Comment: Excellent answer. I'd add that the key commonality between AWS Transit Gateway and Azure VWAN is that both of them are managed solutions that take care of the  components of a hub & spoke architecture (e.g. Firewall, Routing, Network Peering  etc.). This is in contrast to customer-managed solutions where you run AWS Direct Connect or Azure Express Route into your own hub VPC and manage routing and firewall yourself. AWS also recently announced AWS Cloud WAN, which replaces TGW and is even closer in capabilities to Azure VWAN.

Answer (score 1):

For Azure I'd recommend using a transit vnet topology which is basically a hub and spoke network. There's an Azure [blog post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/create-a-transit-vnet-using-vnet-peering/) on it published by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with AWS Transit Gateway enough, but maybe take a look at Azure Virtual WAN. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-wan/virtual-wan-about

Azure Firewall is more of a security appliance than a connection appliance. You would still need a VPN Gateway (or ExR or Peering) to connect to remote networks.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/tutorial-hybrid-ps

I believe the question is a bit too vague to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think Azure has exactly same kind of offering but gateway transit for VNets peering is something  that you might find useful

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-peering-gateway-transit